# White notification icon on Android Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-6.0-marshmallow

Since I am using card view my minimim sdk is for adroid Lollipop 
and I know from Lollipop you have to use transparent icon for notification bar

I have created a transparent notification icon (32x32) and stored it in drawable

But whenever I am sending the notification I am seeing a white circle instead of my icon

Comment: What do you mean by "whenever I am sending the notification". Are you referring to FCM messages or notifications built by the NotificationCompat.Builder class?

Comment: Sending notifcations from Firebase to check the app

Answer (score 1):

Add the *icon* parameter to your notification payload.

You can read more [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support), Table 2b.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use [android assets generator](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_example) for generating the notification icon and then download and place all icons in your `res` directory. 
Also send the same icon name from your notification service provider (FCM, OneSignal etc) and it will work like charm.